# Data range expression for an enumeration in Protégé

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology, description-logic

I would like to define the range of a data type property as an exhaustive enumeration of strings, in a way that an individual could have as value of this property only one of the strings in the enumeration.

For example, a data type property called "color", which can assume only 3 values: "Red", "Green" and "Blue".

I'm using OWL 2, and Protégé 5.0.

Is there an easy way of doing that using Protégé?

Comment: Yes, the range expression would be `{"Red", "Blue", "Green"}`.  I think this has been answered on Stack Overflow before.  Let me see if I can find the old post.

Comment: See [Using enumerated data type in defining property value for individual in Protege](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686636/using-enumerated-data-type-in-defining-property-value-for-individual-in-protege).

Comment: [Defining DataRange Expression in Protege for a Data Type Property](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24531940/1281433) isn't quite a duplicate, but it may be helpful.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't seem to be able to find an exact duplicate question, though I think that this may have been asked before.  In Protege, you can use a datatype expression to represent an enumeration of literals.  In your case, you can add a range and use the expression:

**{"Red", "Green", "Blue"}**

Comment: For the record, this doesn't work in Protege 5 beta 21. It has been fixed in the current trunk https://github.com/protegeproject/protege/issues/308