# Defining range of legal values for OWL properties in Protege

Tags: properties, semantic-web, owl, protege

How do I define a property to have only two legal values (strings `'foo'` or `'bar'`) in Protege?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data range expression for an enumeration in Protégé](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348064/data-range-expression-for-an-enumeration-in-prot%c3%a9g%c3%a9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select your datatype property,
2. Click on "Ranges" and then from the tab "Built in datatypes" select `xsd:string`.
3. In the tab "Data range expressions" enter `{"foo", "bar"}`
4. Click "OK"

When you enter a value outside this range, some reasoners like Fact++ will show that as inconsistent, others won't.