# Check, if value is valid with custom datatype in SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14173705/1169798) I defined a few RDF/OWL properties with custom datatypes like the following:

```
:myProp a rdf:Property;
    rdfs:range [
      a rdfs:Datatype ;
      owl:onDatatype xsd:float ;
      owl:withRestrictions ( [
        xsd:minInclusive 0 ;
        xsd:maxInclusive 100
      ] )
    ];
```

When querying now for properties, which may include a certain value, my current query looks like this:

```
SELECT ?prop
WHERE {
 ?prop rdfs:range / owl:withRestrictions / rdf:first ?prop_range .
 ?prop_range xsd:minInclusive ?prop_range_min ;
             xsd:maxInclusive ?prop_range_max .
 FILTER( ?prop_range_min < 10 ) .
 FILTER( ?prop_range_max > 10 )
}
```

With `10` as an example value for now. It feels just wrong to do the query in this way.

**So is there a way in SPARQL to check, if a certain value is in the range of a datatype?**

Comment: It looks like you almost have a working solution now (i.e., a SPARQL query that checks whether the value is in the specified range).  What sort of alternative are you looking for?  Note, though, that there are {min,max}{Inclusive,Exclusive} for numbers, and you should be using `<=` and `>=` for the inclusive facets.  There are other facets too, though, like regular expression patterns, etc.  SPARQL is an RDF query language, and XSD datatype validation and OWL querying is a bit more complex.  I don't think you'll find anything "more right" in plain SPARQL.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor An optimal solution for me would be something similar to the other operators like `isLiteral()` or `isURI()`, which would also check the datatype constraints. Currently I see just two options: (a) restrict my datatypes just to use `min/maxInclusive` or (b) have a specific query snippet for each possible combination of the restrictions, which will be a lot of code. So I would like to have something like `isOfType( ?myVal, :someCustomType )` to check, if a given value is within the restrictions defined.

Comment: Many SPARQL endpoints have some options for adding additional functions, so something like `isOfType(?val,?type)` could be an option, but it would be endpoint specific.  XSD and OWL datatype validation is probably more complex than what you 'd want to do in pure SPARQL.